# Why windows g++ doesn't find external header files

Tags: c++, compilation, g++, header-files, nana

**My filename :** `firstnana.cpp`

**Current Folder :** `D:\projects\cpp\guinana`

**My headers :**

```
#include <nana/gui.hpp>
#include <nana/gui/widgets/label.hpp>
#include <nana/gui/widgets/button.hpp>
```

**Compiling :**

```
g++ firstnana.cpp -I./nana/include/nana
```

**Example :**
The `<nana/gui.hpp>` is located in `D:\projects\cpp\guinana\nana\include\nana\gui.hpp`

**The output Error :** 
    `firstnana.cpp:1:24: fatal error: nana/gui.hpp: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.`

Comment: Sure about the `./` actually?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ and closers, please select another reason to close the question, because the selected do not apply at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you already have "nana" directory in your `-I` parameter. Don't repeat it in the includes.

```
#include <gui.hpp>
#include <gui/widgets/label.hpp>
#include <gui/widgets/button.hpp>
```

Comment: How is that answering the question?

Comment: I guess I misread the question - sorry.